# Losing reference to variable while using SocketIO in swift 4

Tags: swift, socket.io

I'm new to Swift and have always been a bit messy when it comes to developing for iOS so bear with me.

So in my AppDelegate I have a variable like such

```
var manager = Manager()
```

and in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I've got

```
let controller = ChatRoomViewController()
self.manager.delegate = controller
self.manager.setup()
self.manager.attemptToIdentify(user:username);
```

In the Manager I've got

```
var connectionManager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://0.0.0.0:8080")!)
var usersName = ""
var socket:SocketIOClient! 
func setup(){
    connectionManager.reconnects = true
    socket = connectionManager.defaultSocket;
    self.setSocketEvents();

    socket.connect();
}
```

This works and I'm able to open up a socket which displays the username on the node.js server. Now when I navigate away from the main view to the chat controller and call

```
   appDelegate.manager.attemptMessage(msg: message);
```

the console tells me that I'm no longer connected. Best I can tell, I'm losing the reference to one of my variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should declare your variable in the `AppDelegate`.

I am using Socket.IO too in one of my app and I prefer use it from a shared instance class. I don't know if you are familar with it, but it is a common architecture in iOS development.

It is based on a singleton instance and allows you to keep instance of variables in memory during all the life of the app.

For you case, you can do the following for example:

```
private let _managerSharedInstance = Manager()

class Manager() {

    private var connectionManager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: "http://0.0.0.0:8080")!)
    private var usersName = ""
    private var socket:SocketIOClient!

    var delegate: UIViewController?

    class var shared: Manager {
        return _managerSharedInstance
    }

    init() {
        connectionManager.reconnects = true
        socket = connectionManager.defaultSocket;
        setSocketEvents();
        socket.connect();
    }

    private func setSocketEvents() {
        // Your socket events logic
    }

    func attemptToIdentify(user username: String) {
        socket.emit("identify", ["username": username])
    }

    func attemptToSend(message: String) {
        socket.emit("message", ["username": username, "message": message])
    }

}
```

So, in your `AppDelegate.didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, you can now call:

```
Manager.shared.attemptToIdentify(user: username)
```

You can call this from everywhere in your code, the `shared` class variable will return the instance of `_managerSharedInstance`.

By the way, you should set your delegate of the controller in the `viewWillAppear` of that controller and not in the `AppDelegate`.

```
func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    Manager.shared.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: This is great, I've refactored the manager class with your recommendations but I'm getting error "Type 'Manager' has no member 'shared'" in my AppDelegate when calling "Manager.shared.attemptToIdentify(user: username)"

Comment: Hi @user3251122, sorry for the delay of my answer. There was a typo error in my example: it was not `class var manager` but `class var shared`. It is now fixed. Regards, IMACODE.

Answer (score 1):

You set `controller` variable's object in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method to your manager's delegate. But when you navigate `ChatRoomViewController` on UI, you open another `ChatRoomViewController` object.

You should set manager's delegate in your `ChatRoomViewController` class' `viewDidLoad` method like this

```
class ChatRoomViewController: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad(){
         super.viewDidLoad()
         appDelegate.manager.delegate = self
    }
}
```